# python test delete from mongo

Tags: python, mongodb, selenium

I have a problem with mongo. When I ended my automation tests, I need trash all data and object which I created. I create a script. In this script I delete a rows from a few table. But when I start this, This class doesn't start, where is my problem?
In consol I haven't any message, zero value.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

class deleteMongo():

    def deleteFirst(self):
        client = MongoClient('databaseaddress')
        db = client.TableData
        db.Employe.delete_one({"name": "EmployeOne"})

    def deleteSecond(self):
        client = MongoClient('databaseaddress')
        db = client.PersonData
        db.Person.delete_one({"name": "PersonOne"})

    def deleteThird(self):
        client = MongoClient('databaseaddress')
        db = client.AutoData
        db.Auto.delete_one({"name": "AutoThird"})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding your question correctly, you are trying to run the script above and it's not doing anything?

If this is your complete ***module***, you are not calling the class at all, but defining the class **object**.

also the parenthesis in `class deleteMongo():` are redundant in a class, since it always inherits the `object`. On the current setup of this **class** object, you should use `def` instead, or setup your class to **initialize** shared objects of the class.

Based on your current code, try this:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

class deleteMongo:
    def __init__(self, databaseAddress):
        # if the databseAddress is always the same, you can remove it from the arguments
        # and hardcode it here
        self.client = MongoClient(databaseAddress)

    def deleteFirst(self):
        db = self.client.TableData
        db.Employe.delete_one({"name": "EmployeOne"})

    def deleteSecond(self):
        db = self.client.PersonData
        db.Person.delete_one({"name": "PersonOne"})

    def deleteThird(self):
        db = self.client.AutoData
        db.Auto.delete_one({"name": "AutoThird"})
```

and then when you need to call one of the class functions, call it like this:

```
deleteMongo(databaseAddress='someaddress').deleteFirst()
```